# UIScrollView Vertical Scroll + Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to do something simple, yet Apple loves to overcomplicate things for developers (quite ironic). I want to create a vertically scrollable screen. Basically a longer screen that I can scroll through. The problem is that it either doesn't scroll or the content (a label for demo purposes) is fixed on the screen (e.g. centered).

I looked at multiple tutorials but still didn't fully understand it because the inner workings aren't fully explained.

So from what I understand, it goes the following:

- You place a `UIScrollView` on top of the main `UIView`
- You set the `UIScrollView`'s margins to 0-0-0-0
- You place a content view `UIView` inside the `UIScrollView`
- You set it's margins to 0-0-0-0 related to both the main `UIView` and the `UIScrollView`
- You set the `UIScrollView` and content `UIView`'s height & width (in my case I chose 1000 for height and screen width for width since I want only vertical scroll)
- You set the `UIScrollView.contentSize` to something bigger than the screen
- You add the content and align it to the content `UIView`

So what am I missing or adding when I shouldn't? If anyone can explain how this is done quickly, please do so.

Comment: Have you added your constraints properly.................There is an option to reset to suggested constraints and add missing constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a lot of this is wrong:

> So from what I understand, it goes the following:
>
> You place a UIScrollView on top of the main UIView
>
> You set the UIScrollView's margins to 0-0-0-0
>
> You place a content view UIView inside the UIScrollView
>
> You set it's margins to 0-0-0-0 related to both the main UIView and the UIScrollView
>
> You set the UIScrollView and content UIView's height & width (in my case I chose 1000 for height and screen width for width since I want only vertical scroll)
>
> You set the UIScrollView.contentSize to something bigger than the screen
>
> You add the content and align it to the content UIView

There are various strategies for making a scroll view scrollable under auto layout. The "content view" strategy is perfectly valid, and very convenient, though it is not the only possible strategy. Since you seem to imply you want to use it, let's use it:

- Pin the scroll view's top, bottom, left, and right with constraints to main view. Typically these constraints will have a zero constant, but no law requires this.
- Give the scroll view exactly one immediate subview, a "content view". Pin the content view's top, bottom, left, and right with constraints to the scroll view. These constraints *must* have a zero constant.
- Give the content view height and width constraints. Set their constant values absolutely. Experimentally, use large numbers. As you've said, width of zero and height of 1000 will give you vertical scrolling on a screen smaller than 1000 height.

Now *stop*. Don't add any more constraints, and don't set the scroll view's content size in any other way. You are *finished*. The scroll view is now scrollable, even though there is nothing visible inside it — provided the height or width constraints constant values are larger than the actual height or width of the scroll view at runtime. And you can run the project and *see* that this is true.

You are now free to populate the content view.

Comment: This is a downloadable project that implements the strategy described above: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch07p367scrollViewInNibAutolayout2 Other example projects in the repository demonstrate other strategies.

Comment: ^^ trust this guy... he wrote the book!!

Comment: @matt could you please expand on why the content view's constraints must have a zero constant? It works fine for me with the standard margins, for example. Also, about your final bullet point; setting explicit widths and heights doesn't seem to be the best solution in most cases. Could it be better to a) allow the content view's content to define its width and height, or b) clip the content view laterally to the `view` and vertically to the `scrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put a UIView inside the scroll view. You can just add whatever objects you want and set objects frame within the scrollview.  The scrollable area is set by the contentSize property of UIScrollView.

Some things you will want to make sure to do:

1) Add `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` to your .h file

2) set `scrollview.delegate = self;`

3) Set scrollview.contentsize = CGSizeMake(something bigger than the screen)

4) make sure the scrollview is scrollable with `scrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;`